# Image file suggestions not showing up in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to import image in my react app using the import keyword from a local directory but I can't see any image files in the code suggestion. I have tried to type the entire path without using the suggestions but the image still won't load on my web application. Below are the links to the files.

[screenshot of import statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7rsg.png)

[screenshot of image location in the src folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9pMg.png)

Comment: I am dumb, i had the wrong import in the parent component. Appreciate the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is put images into the public folder and use it like this:

```js
<img src="/img1.jpg" />
```

in your situation,
how do you created your react project? with `create-react-app`?
if yes https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/ there is simple solution for this... let's give a import image from same path with extension

Answer (score -1):

Hi Just Moeed first import the image you in the screenshot in post import Image
in  this Image in src the name of import